# Estimates of the sum of the biggest terms in a binomial expansion.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

Perhaps this is an easy and standard result in the binomial distribution. Consider the expansion $(a+b)^n$ where $a=(\frac{1}{2} +\delta)$ and $b=(\frac{1}{2}-\delta)$ for some arbitrarily small $\delta$.
Given a fixed small $0<c<1$, one would expect for all $n$ large enough, the existence of $t=t(\delta,n,c)< \frac{n}{2}$ so that with the initial $t$ terms of the binomial expansion we have $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{t} {n\choose j} a^j b^{n-j}>c$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S_n$ be a random variable with binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $b$.  Then your sum $$\sum_{j=0}^t {n \choose j} a^j b^{n-j} = \mathbb P(S_n \le t)$$
By the Law of Large Numbers,
$ \mathbb P(S_n \le r n) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ for any $r > b$.  In particular, taking $b < r < 1/2$ and  $t = r n < n/2$ we have $\mathbb P(S_n \le t) > c$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Your expectation that $t$ is a decreasing function of $n$, let alone rapidly decreasing, is not at all true.  The same Law of Large Numbers says
$\mathbb P(S_n \le r n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ if $0 < r < b$. And for $t = b n$, the Central Limit Theorem says $\mathbb P(S_n \le bn) \to 1/2$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: One would actually expect $t$ to be of the form $\mathbb{E}[S_n] - C\cdot \sqrt{n}$ (where $C$ is a constant depending only on $\delta$ and $c$. Basically most of the probability mass is around the expectation, give or take a few standard deviations.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't the parameter of the binomial be $a$, not $b$?

Comment: I edited out the last paragraph where I said t should be rapidly decreasing. That is obviously not true.